# Laravel - Parameterized route full acces only for admin, but specific access to user logged

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

I'm buiding a user management system. The current routes on web.php are here:

```
Route::middleware(['admin'])
    ->prefix('users')
    ->name('users.')
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('management/list', '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@list');
        Route::resource('management', '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController');
    });
```

I have two levels of user: `Administrator` (middleware is `admin`) and `Collaborator` (middleware is `auth`).

My problem is with the route of `edit` and `update` from the users resource: `users/management/{management}/edit`

How can I do something like that to the users from auth middleware, to allow the route just if the parameter be the own user id for the Collaborator users?

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])
    ->prefix('users')
    ->name('users.')
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('management/{auth()->id}/edit', '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit');
    });
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding | https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#creating-policies

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this however you can just look up the user again in your controller

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])
    ->prefix('users')
    ->name('users.')
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('management/currentuser/edit', '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit');
    });
```

This is also better practice as you are looking up logged in user not any user.